# Зачем нужен get prop()?

Tags: javascript

```js
let user = {
  name: "John",
  surname: "Smith",

  get fullName() {
    return `${this.name} ${this.surname}`;
  },

  set fullName(value) {
    [this.name, this.surname] = value.split(" ");
  }
};

// set fullName is executed with the given value.
user.fullName = "Alice Cooper";

alert(user.name); // Alice
alert(user.surname); // Cooper
```

Вот пример, где можно убрать get и ничего не измениться, так зачем он вообще нужен?

Comment: Если не нужно брать объединение свойств в виде fullName или установка имени и фамилии через fullName - то тогда не нужен.

Answer (score 0):

```js
alert(user.fullName );
```

А вот без геттера сделать нельзя
А без сеттера нельзя сделать вот так

```js
user.fullName = "Alice Cooper";
```